# ¿Cómo obtener el numero de columnas y rows para una matriz en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Por ejemplo te dan la matriz en esta forma:

```
def Surface(a)
 #aqui quisiera recuperar el numero de columnas y en otra variable el numero
 #de rows matriz, que es una array [0,0][0,1]... y cada punto tiene un
 #valor, como: 1,2,3...
end
```

Comment: Pero ¿qué has hecho sobre ese ejercicio? en general, preguntas del tipo "¿quién puede hacerme esta tarea?" no tienen buena aceptación. Revisa [ask] para que veas como puedes mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos hehehe, esa no es una tarea, es una base para hacer una tarea de verdad complicada, pero quisiera saber, como se puede sacar el numero de rows o el numero de columnas, quizas existe una funcion que te devuelve tales valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si a es una matriz:

a.size te devuelve el número de filas de la matriz.

a[0].size te devuelve el número de columnas de la primera fila de la matriz.

Comment: muchas gracias, eso si es muy util :3

Comment: Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la documentación de Ruby; es muy buena.  https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html

Comment: gracias, ya lo habia leido, solo pensaba que quizas algo se me habia pasado y habia alguna funcion mas simple para retornar estos valores, pero la informacion fue muy precisa y certera, muchas gracias :)